# Faster Wine application opening

Tags: wine

[***Translation***]
I want to open a game (*Killing Floor*) which in Windows opens very fast but when I try to the same in Ubuntu I find it slow.

Is there a way of opening .exe files in Ubuntu faster using more RAM or any other tricks?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

[***Original***]
Bueno mi duda es que quiero abrir un juego (killing floor) el cual es un exe que en Windows me va bastante rapido, sin embargo al abrirlo desde Ubuntu me va lento, ¿hay alguna manera de abrir archivos exe con mas RAM o algo que haga que vaya rapido? gracias.

Uso Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of things you can probably do to help:

1) Add the `wineserver` program to your startup applications, so that it starts when you log in, and is always running.

2) Run `wine-preloader /path/to/yourgame.exe`, so that wine adds some of its data to a preload cache.

I'm not sure how much, if at all, these will speed up the startup process for the game. I don't use wine much, but haven't noticed any particularly long startup times with it, beyond the first run (when it builds font caches and such).

Comment: Running `wineserver --persistent` noticeably decreases startup time of .exe files for me. From about 3 seconds to open down to about 1 second to open, maybe less. Without `--persistent` (aka `-p`) wineserver will by default timeout and close after 3 seconds of no use.

Answer (score 0):

All these solutions like wine preloaders with or without --persistent **didn't work for me**.

However, I have **found a tool here** ( https://xprofan.net/intl/en/applications/wine-speedup-programstarts/ ) that actually works and the program starts are astonishingly noticeably faster.

Comment: I, personally would be wary of installing an .exe from a website that appears to have little to no techncal details about it on the webpage you linked to. Could you provide more/any details about this?

Comment: Hi, in principle you are absolutely right. In this case, however, it is a platform by and for developers who are verified by name & address. The developers there are apparently very willing to give out any infos. So you can get the source code there and compile the program yourself. In this case it is probably a trustworthy websource that has been working for many years. The tool has been running for a few days now & I can't imagine without it. It doesn't cause any network traffic or seemingly any other trouble. (which unfortunately cannot be said of most prods from established manufacturers)